# AutoMapper Infinite Loop using EF Code First

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

I have the following classes (One-One relationship Asset-TrackingDevice):

```
public class Asset
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public TrackingDevice TrackingDevice { get; set; }

    }

public class TrackingDevice
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Imei { get; set; }
        public int? AssetId { get; set; }
        public Asset Asset { get; set; }
    }
```

The viewModels are very similar:

```
public class AssetViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int? TrackingDeviceId { get; set; }
        public TrackingDeviceViewModel TrackingDevice { get; set; }

    }
public class TrackingDeviceViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }       
        public string Imei { get; set; }
        public AssetViewModel Asset { get; set; }
        public string AssetId { get; set; }
    }
```

Mappings:

```
CreateMap<Asset, AssetViewModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.TrackingDevice, map => map.Ignore());
CreateMap<AssetViewModel, Asset>()
                .ForMember(d => d.TrackingDevice, map => map.Ignore());
CreateMap<AssetViewModel, Asset>()
                .ReverseMap();
CreateMap<TrackingDevice, TrackingDeviceViewModel>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Asset, map => map.Ignore());
CreateMap<TrackingDeviceViewModel, TrackingDevice>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Asset, map => map.Ignore());
CreateMap<TrackingDevice, TrackingDeviceViewModel>()
                .ReverseMap();
```

When I perform a database query to obtain the TrackingDevices, 
I get an error because in the mapping the Asset within Tracking Device also includes a Tracking Device and so on.

The query that I execute to obtain the tracking devices is:

```
var trackingDevices = _appContext.TrackingDevices
         .Include(td => td.Asset)
         .ToListAsync();
var trackingMapper = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TrackingDeviceViewModel>>(trackingDevices);
```

I read that by including the Map.Ignore would fix the problem but it did not work either, does anyone know what my error is?

Comment: Upgrade. This works on the latest without any ignore.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Hi, upgrade what¿?

Comment: Upgrade AutoMapper.

Comment: I upgrade AutoMapper to 8.00, I erase all map => map.Ignore()); 
When I have no relationship between Asset and Tracking Device (because it is optional), I can list without problems. But when I modify a tracking device by placing a relation with Asset, it stops working.

Comment: A repro would help. Make a [gist](https://gist.github.com/lbargaoanu/9c7233441c3a3413cc2b9b9ebb5964a9) that we can execute and see fail. Without EF.

Comment: I create a gist the link is: https://gist.github.com/juanjinario/f4b2fc97f6784f089b0783653f694551 ; I dont know for what reason the AutoMapper doesnt work, please help me

Comment: That's not helpful. If you can make a proper repro (look at my gist), I'll take a look.

Comment: I need more information, what is Proper Repro?, I see your Gist but i dont know the diference with my Gist. I just see a One document with model and Automapper, Do yo need just this?

Comment: I want only the AM part, that I can copy paste and execute.

Comment: The problem occurs when the query is executed, the part: var trackingDevices = _appContext.TrackingDevices.Include(td => td.Asset).ToListAsync(); the include part puts an Asset inside of each Tracking Device, and this Asset have a Tracking Device, and the Tracking Device have a Asset 
recursively, I do not know how to prevent the mapping from being done recursively.

Comment: OK, so in fact it's an EF issue. I see. Try lazy loading.

Comment: I dont know, I think that is a AutoMapper problem, please see the statement, In viewModels, AssetViewModel have a TrackingDeviceViewModel property AND TrackingDeviceViewModel have a AssetViewModel property, because I have a ONE-ONE relationship and I need the two Entities in my view, when I apply the Mapper in a Tracking Device ViewModel this have a Asset View Model too and the Asset have a Tracking Device, How I can 
how can I avoid mapping in infinity or control the depth of the mapping?

Comment: I don't think so, but a repro would certainly prove me wrong.